# How to align input box with div

Tags: css, alignment

I am trying to align some stuff in a login page. I want the pictures to appear left to the input boxes and the buttons on the down part of the div to be left and right. Something like this:

[image]

But this is what is happening (on Safari. Chrome works kinda OK as you can see on top image)

[image]

The problem is that although it partially works on Chrome, the input boxes are too small and I can't increase their size.

This is the code I am trying to use:

```css
// Outer white DIV for the forms and buttons:

.login-form {
  width: 360px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 19px 29px 29px 19px;
  color: #444444;
  background: rgba(253, 253, 253, 1.000);

  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  border: solid 1px rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.075);
}

// Login field for e-mail:

.login-field-up {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

/ Login field for password:

.login-field-down {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  float: left;
}

// DIV for Icons of user credential and golden key:

.login-icon {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

// Right checbox:

.right-col {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

Left blue login button: 

.left-col {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;

}
```

If there is any other easy way to do it, I am up to it. Since I have always worked with backend, I suck with CSS.

```
<section id="banner">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <section>
        <div id="skel-layers-wrapper" class="login-form">
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'principal' %}">
                <div class="login-icon">
                    <img src="{% static "icons/identity.png" %}" class="icons">
                </div>
                <div class="login-field-up">
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="E-mail" />
                </div>
                <div class="login-icon">
                    <img src="{% static "icons/key_user.png" %}" class="icons">
                </div>
                <div class="login-field-down">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="username" placeholder="Password" />
                </div>
                <div class="left-col">
                        <input type="submit" value="Login!" class="button" />
                </div>
                <div class="right-col">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="remember_login" checked="" name="remember_login" class="6u$ 12u$(3)">
                    <label for="remember_login" style="color:#5C5C5C">Remember me <img src="{% static "icons/lock_gold_16.png" %}" class="icons"></label>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for it?

Comment: Can you also provide your HTML and put it into a stack snippet? @JohnBupit using a stack snippet is better as it doesn't require users to leave the site and also means we aren't relying on a third party service.

Comment: seems like something is to big to float next to the icon. It's also good practice to use `clear` ^^

Comment: Try removing all the `margin: right`s and replace them with something else.

Comment: Hi @E. Camilo, I have formatted your CSS into a stack snippet. This should make it easy for you to drop your HTML into your post and then it will be easier for us to provide an answer.

Comment: You may have to use a list (`<ul></ul>`) if it is not the case yet.

Comment: I have edited and added the HTML code I am using. As you can see, I use DIVs for each of the elements.

Comment: @Billy I have done it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the size of your input boxes by setting the "font-size" attribute in your style sheet, for example,

`input {
    font-size:2em;
}`

And you can align images with input boxes by using `<label></label>`, for example,

`<label for="email"><img src="image.png" /></label> 
<input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" />`

Or, you can also place the images in a separate div and the inputs in another div and then adjust the width, margin or padding to align them the way you want.

But as Billy said, if you post your html code, it will be easier to provide a solution.

**EDIT:** Thanks for your code. I think you wanted to achieve something like this. I added some borders to help you understand the positioning of the divs. Remove them and change the urls for the images once you are done debugging.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

 <style>
 
  .login-form {
  width: 360px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 19px 29px 29px 19px;
  color: #444444;
  background: rgba(253, 253, 253, 1.000);
  
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  border: solid 1px rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.075);
  
  border:1px solid black;
  }
  
        #title-header {
            text-align:center;
        }

  #username, #password {
   margin-left:20px;
  }
  
  input {
   font-size:1em;
  }
  
  img {
   width:16px;
   height:16px;
  }
  
  .login-field-up {
  margin-left:50px;
  width:250px;
  border:1px solid black;
  }
  
  .login-field-down {
  margin-left:50px;
  width:250px;  
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  }

  .login-icon {
  border:1px solid black;
  }

  .right-col {
  float:left;
  width:160px;
  margin-left:30px;
  border:1px solid black;
  }

  .left-col {
  margin-left:50px;
  float:left;
  width:60px;
  border:1px solid red;
  }
  
  .inner-wrapper {
   margin-top:50px;
   width:350px;
   height:150px;
   border:1px solid red;
  }
  
 </style>


<section id="banner">
    <h2 id="title-header">Title</h2>
    <section>
        <div id="skel-layers-wrapper" class="login-form">
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'principal' %}">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
     <div class="login-field-up">
      <img src="image.png">
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="E-mail" />
     </div>
     <div class="login-field-down">
       <img src="image.png">
       <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
     </div>
     <div class="left-col">
       <input type="submit" value="Login!" class="button" />
     </div>
     <div class="right-col">
      <input type="checkbox" id="remember_login" checked="" name="remember_login" class="6u$ 12u$(3)">
      <label for="remember_login" style="color:#5C5C5C">Remember me <img src="{% static "icons/lock_gold_16.png" %}" class="icons"></label>
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</section>
```

Comment: I use different divs as you can see, however when I set the margins it goes totally crazy. When I debug with Chrome it looks distorted and the margins in the div with the forms seems to send the div with he pictures out of alignment.

Comment: Deep, thank you for your dedication, however it is still not working. I can see your code works perfectly if I create a new HTML, but when I put it on my page goes back to what I had before. http://i.imgur.com/6zqLaGG.png

It must be inheriting something from my style.css. I will keep debugging and see what is wrong with this thing.

Comment: I found out my CSS was overwriting the margin-left:20px; attribute, making the icons spaceless.